# Group and Sort collection using Java 8

Tags: java, list, sorting, java-8, grouping

I have a list of Object say Car. First I want to group the collection on some field say `carCompanyId`. So I will have something like,

```
Map<Integer, List<Car>> = cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getCarCompanyId))
```

I want every list in above Map to be sorted by one of the fields. Can I achieve this by adding parameter to grouping by function so that it sorts the list while grouping it.

Comment: @tunaki This question is very different from the one you marked it as duplicate.

Comment: No it is not, you want to sort a List according to one of its fields. Which is what the linked question answers in the general sense.

Comment: @tunaki : I want to group it and sort it simultaneously.

Comment: You can use the downstream with `Collectors::toList` and a finisher function. `Map<Integer, List<Car>> map = cars.stream().collect(groupingBy(Car::getCarCompanyId, collectingAndThen(toList(), list -> {
  list.sort(comparingInt(Car::getCarMetric));
  return list;
})));`

Comment: @Flown: since `toList()` doesn’t guaranty to return a mutable list, you have to use `toCollection(ArrayList::new)` instead, if you want to sort it afterwards. Of course, it’s simpler to chain a `sorted(comparingInt(Car::getCarMetric))` before the `collect` operation…